# Creating a CLI shell accessible by telnet using Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, simulation, telnet

This a project for the simulation of a Cisco switch interface. I basically want to create a command line interface which I can telnet to.

If anyone is familiar with the Cisco switched this is primarily how they are controlled. I want to generate the simulated outputs of the commands on these switches. I tried using the twisted framework and the cmd option of python.

But I just need something simple, basically a module that would telnet to the cli, then I can use the commands as i see fit in a different modules and then display the commands.

I would appreciate if someone would show me the right way to do this, or even what I could use.(The telnet option is not mandatory.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/telnetsrvlib/1.0.2) seems the ticket; simple but workable. Its a telnet server library written in Python. Its easily extendable; like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    "Testing - Accept a single connection"
    class TNS(SocketServer.TCPServer):
        allow_reuse_address = True

    class TNH(TelnetHandler):
        def cmdECHO(self, params):
            """ [<arg> ...]
            Echo parameters
            Echo command line parameters back to user, one per line.
            """
            self.writeline("Parameters:")
            for item in params:
                self.writeline("\t%s" % item)
        def cmdTIME(self, params):
            """
            Print Time
            Added by dilbert
            """
            self.writeline(time.ctime())

    logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    tns = TNS(("0.0.0.0", 8023), TNH)
    tns.serve_forever()
```

Comment: It is not running directly..I get the following error

File "C:\Python27\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 15,in <module>
    from _curses import *
    ImportError: No module named _curses'

 Are there any other dependencies?

Comment: True, the module depends on curses. If you're running this on a *nix, then curses should be trivial to install. If you're running this on Windows; these packages should work: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses

Comment: New Error:'unable to find SocketServer'. When I do from telnetsrvlib import *, I get this error :'module' object has no attribute 'TelnetCLIHandler'.

Comment: What python version and platform are you running? I can't recreate these errors on 64bit Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: python 2.7.5 and windows 7 64bit

Comment: Change Line 39 of telnetsrvlib.py from __all__ = ["TelnetHandler", "TelnetCLIHandler"] to __all__ = ["TelnetHandler"]

Comment: the SocketServer error still persists. name SocketServer is not defined

Comment: It seems that SocketServer is standard library according to this http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html. Possibly try import socketserver in a python shell and see what happens.